# Why does the HTML popup not display?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an info button that users can click on to learn more about my site through a popup modual. When testing it on the live server, clicking the button makes the background color darker, but the popup modual itself is nowhere to be seen. Please let me know what I have overlooked in my code that might be causing this error. Thank you!

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- style.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

    <!-- Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Modal Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Info Button -->
    <div class="container buttons" id="info-button"> 
        <button class="btn rounded-btn">?</button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-container" id="modal_container">
        <div class="modal">
            <h1>Modal Test</h1>
            <p>Test text!</p>
            <button id="close-info">Close me</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- index.js -->
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**style.css**

```
body {
    background-color: #363062;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.text {
    color: #E9D5DA;
}

.buttons {
    padding-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.btn {
    background-color: #827397;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
}

.rounded-btn { 
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

#info-button { 
    justify-content: end;
    align-items:flex-end;
}

.modal-container { 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position:fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    height: 100vh; 
    width: 100vw;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.modal-container.show { 
    pointer-events: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}

.modal { 
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    width: 600px;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.modal h1 { 
    margin: 0; 
}

.modal p { 
    font-size: 14px; 
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

**index.js**

```
const open = document.getElementById('info-button');
const close = document.getElementById('close-info');
const modal_container = document.getElementById('modal_container');

open.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    modal_container.classList.add('show');
});

close.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    modal_container.classList.remove('show');
});
```

Comment: because the .modal class has display none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap lib has already a class .modal so you have to rename your .modal class to something else and it should works. I've tested.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still pretty new to all this, so I didn't realize that naming the class .modal would cause an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was interfering with the Bootstap CSS Lib. which already has a default styling behavior for modals etc.

Below, I was able to fix your issue using the bootstrap custom modal system and it works perfectly.

```js
$("#myModal").modal()
```

```css
body {
      background-color: #363062;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.text {
      color: #E9D5DA;
}

.buttons {
      padding-top: 20px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
}

.btn {
      background-color: #827397;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 10px;
}

.rounded-btn {
      padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
      border-radius: 100%;
}

#info-button {
      justify-content: end;
      align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
            <!-- Info Button -->
            <div class="container buttons" id="info-button">
                  <button class="btn rounded-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_container">?</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="modal_container" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                  aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                              <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Modal Test</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>Test text!</p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close
                                          Me</button>
                              </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </div>


            <!-- Bootstrap JS -->
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
                  integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
                  crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                  integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
                  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            <!-- Custom JS -->
            <script src="index.js" defer></script>
      </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have just started learning bootstrap recently, so I appreciate the help